# Why is this command exploding

Tags: bash

So I got this as an answer to a previous question as an answer for looking recursively through files in a directory and deleting the files and directories if found:

```
find \( -name ".git" -o -name ".gitignore" -o -name "Documentation" \) -exec rm -rf "{}" \;
```

There are two problems with this:

One:

```
find: `./adam.balan/AisisAjax/.git': No such file or directory
```

because of this error the rest of the script doesn't execute. Now I don't want to have to check for any of the files or folders. I don't care if they exist or not, I want to suppress the error on this.

The second is that I am also getting the error on a directory that needs to be excluded from this search: `vendor/`

```
find: `./vendor/adam.balan/AisisAjax/.git': No such file or directory
```

I do not want it searching vendor. I want it to leave vendor alone.

How do I solve these two problems? Suppression and ignoring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're deleting a directory that `find` then tries to descend into. You can use `-prune` to prevent that:

```
find \( -name ".git" -o -name ".gitignore" -o -name "Documentation" \) -prune -exec rm -rf "{}" \;
```

To ignore all errors, you can use `2> /dev/null` to squash the error messages, and `|| true` to avoid `set -e` making your script exit:

```
find \( -name ".git" -o -name ".gitignore" -o -name "Documentation" \) -prune -exec rm -rf "{}" \; 2> /dev/null || true
```

Finally, to avoid descending any directory named 'vendor', you can use `-prune` again:

```
find -name vendor -prune -o \( -name ".git" -o -name ".gitignore" -o -name "Documentation" \) -prune -exec rm -rf "{}" \; 2> /dev/null || true
```